# How to save arrays of different length into an array variable of a list in R

Tags: arrays, list, r, dataframe

I want to use a list to save two arrays of the same length. One array (`folders`) contains names of folders and the other (`files`) contains arrays of filenames, which might be of different length.

```
mvExp = list(
    folders     = NULL,
    files       = NULL
)

mvExp$folders[1] = "../data_america/"
mvExp$files[1]  = c("file1.dat")

mvExp$folders[2] = "../data_europe"
mvExp$files[2]  = c("file1.dat", "file2.dat", "file3.dat")
```

When I try to add the array of filenames to the second field of the array "files", I recieve a warning, which says, that the number of elements I want to add is too long. "file2.dat", "file3.dat" are not saved to `mvExp$files[2]`.

**How can I save arrays of different length into a list?**

I also tried to use a ´data.frame´ (since my two arrays have the same length), but I was not able to add elements to the data.frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whereas `mvExp$folders` can be a simple character vector (containing one string for each folder), `mvExp$files` needs to be a list, so that some of its elements can *themselves* contain several elements (i.e. the files in a directory).

To make it work, your code needs two changes:

- `file` needs to be 'initialized' as a list.
- To assign new elements to the list, use the `"[[<-"` operator rather than the `"[<-"` operator.

.

```
mvExp = list(
    folders     = character(),
    files       = list()
)

mvExp$folders[1] <- "../data_america/"
mvExp$files[[1]] <- c("file1.dat")

mvExp$folders[2] <- "../data_europe"
mvExp$files[[2]] <- c("file1.dat", "file2.dat", "file3.dat")
```

Comment: Good answer but could you pls replace "=" with "<-" per R standards?

Answer (score 1):

You can store everything in a single list.

```
myExp <- list(
  `../data_america` = "file.dat",
  `../data_europe`  = c("file1.dat", "file2.dat", "file3.dat")
)
```

Retrive the folder names like this

```
names(myExp)
```

and the files for a given folder with, e.g.,

```
myExp[["../data_america"]]
```